# Excel Form buttons remain in same place, but TopLeftCell is different (all after parent row is unhidden)

Tags: vba, excel, button

Cutting right to the chase, I have a tab with 4 Excel Tables stacked on top of each other. Each row has its own "up" and "down" buttons in the column to the left of the table, like this:

[image]

I shrunk the buttons to fit within the same cell (rowheight of 20). This allowed me to use the cell's `TopLeftCell.Row` property as follows: When clicked, stuff from the button's row is copy-pasted to the row above/below. This is the basic code:

```
currRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
If InStr(Application.Caller, "Up") > 0 Then
    Move_Project_Up currRow
Else
    Move_Project_Down currRow
End If
```

When the user gets to this tab, any empty table-rows are hidden (with a `Rows(rr).EntireRow.Hidden = True`). The buttons `Move and size with cells` so they are automatically hidden). All visible buttons work as expected. However, sometimes a user wishes to move a project from the top of one table "up" to the bottom of the above table (i.e. to a currently hidden row). You can imagine wanting to move data from row 312 "up" to row 244 in the image below:

[image]

The code successfully makes the move and unhides the row. HERE'S THE PROBLEM: when the row is unhidden, the buttons are dark gray and their `TopLeftCell.Row` is wrong:

[image]

They are NOT disabled. When clicked, they still trigger the assigned macro. However, I can see from a `Debug.Print` that their `TopLeftCell.Row` is not necessarily the row they are actually in. In the image above, BOTH SETS OF BUTTONS have a `TopLeftCell.Row` of 97. That's correct for the first set, but not the second.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? I suspect it has to do with the unhiding of the rows, and/or the fact that there's a lot happening on this tab (e.g. over 10,000 array formulas).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Controls are finicky at best, especially the ActiveX ones, but the form ones too and I see things like this happening a lot. What I did once is have a hidden column containing button names and each time rows are hidden or shown run a routine that moves the buttons back into place and hide the ones on hidden rows. The controls were set not to move or resize because that also caused a lot of havoc.

Comment: I didn't set the controls to not move or size because then they wouldn't hide with the rows. BUT...MOVING THE BUTTONS BACK INTO PLACE WORKED!!! I'm not super familiar with StackOverflow; would you like to post this as an answer? Or should I answer my own question and refer back to your coment

Comment: Reply to your original question with the answer and the steps you took to resolve it, then mark it as answered. That way it can help people if they come looking with a similar problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one commenter (jkpieterse) suggested, setting the `.Top` property of the "broken" buttons to the `.Top` value of a cell in the same row worked!